# How to get multiple array JSON Data

Tags: php, json

I have Json Data with multiple array, and i try to get the data inside effect_property, but it keep return nothing.

Here is my code

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json');
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);

for($i = 0; $i < $count_data_action; $i++){
    $path_data_action =  $json_data[t03_action][data][$i][effect_property];
}
```

when i print the $path_data_action it show something like this:

```
{"duration":1,"delay":0,"propTo":{"source":"image","source_path":"../uploads/17041409353289557288/","source_file":"1704141604180616.jpg","source_name":"image1.jpg"},"beforeAction":"0","action_order":"1"}
```

How can i get the source_path?

Comment: `$path_data_action['propTo']['source_path']`?

Comment: still doesn't show anything..

Comment: Looks like you have JSON inside JSON then. Include your JSON document in the question. And turn on error_reporting. You should see many notices.

Comment: Do you have nested JSON? Can you show it all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the JSON you are decoding with :

```
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);
```

contains another JSON string at key *effect_property*. You could change that to JSON Object and it should work fine.

Otherwise, you could use *json_decode* again, like :

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count_data_action; $i++){
     $path_data_action =  $json_data[t03_action][data][$i]effect_property];
     $pathDataActionArr = json_decode($path_data_action , true);
     $sourcePath = $pathDataActionArr['propTo']['sourcePath'];
}
```

Furthermore, to know any last occurred error with JSON encoding/decoding
[json_last_error — Returns the last error occurred](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

**UPDATE** : I tried to decode the JSON you posted with code :

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents("/home/tarun/Desktop/test/abcd");
$jsonArray = json_decode($fileContent,true);
var_dump($jsonArray['t03_action']['data'][9]['effect_property']);
$effectPropertyArr = json_decode($jsonArray['t03_action']['data'][9]['effect_property'],true);

if(isset($effectPropertyArr['propTo']['source_path'])) {
    var_dump($effectPropertyArr['propTo']['source_path']);  
} else {
    var_dump("No such key!");
}
```

Here, not all your elements of the array at key *effect_property* contains *source_path*. That's why :

```
if(isset($effectPropertyArr['propTo']['source_path'])) {
```

The above is working fine, with output :

> /home/tarun/Desktop/test/temp.php:6:
> string(205) "{"duration":1,"delay":0,"propTo":{"source":"image","source_path":"../uploads/18032022375907620062/","source_file":"1804100413270066.jpg","source_name":"Penguins.jpg"},"beforeAction":"0","action_order":"1"}"
> /home/tarun/Desktop/test/temp.php:10:
> string(32) "../uploads/18032022375907620062/"

Comment: i already try to decode it again but nothing change, i also try to use JSON.parse(), i'm not sure what is wrong

Comment: Could you add a pastebin link with the sample JSON, if its not confidential. That will help.

Comment: One is, there is a format error in the JSON you posted. '}' needs to be added at the end. But I guess, its not the case with the  actual JSON otherwise json_decode() would have thrown an error.

Comment: I tried to decode it. I updated my answer. Give it a try.

Comment: Wah, Thank you soo muchh! it really work well! and can you help me 1 more thing? i need to change that source path to another id, any idea?

Comment: You could dynamically add another key at any level. So do $arr[...[new key]] = $sourcePath. Then unset($arr[...[source_path]])

Answer (score 0):

```
// decoded array passed key of that array
$json_data['propTo']['source_path'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this ,Its working for me.

  var data =  {"duration":1,"delay":0,"propTo":{"source":"image","source_path":"../uploads/17041409353289557288/","source_file":"1704141604180616.jpg","source_name":"image1.jpg"},"beforeAction":"0","action_order":"1"}
            alert(data.duration);
            var Prop = data.propTo;
            alert(Prop.source_path);`enter code here`
```